# CSS font color style not applied

Tags: html, css, colors

Why is the font color for paragraph text not changing to red?

I haven't applied any other CSS styles, so this shouldn't be an issue with style overriding right?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <style>
    p {
      color=red;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <p id="msg1">message 1</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Not `color=red;`. Try `color: red;` instead.

Comment: You need to learn basic CSS syntax. `=` should be `:`.

Comment: ahh whoops should've caught that -.-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`color: red;` would be the correct CSS-syntax. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

CSS syntax error... 
use ':' instead of '=' inside the style..

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your CSS syntax.

```
<style>
p {
  color: red;
}
</style>
```

You could also target with the ID by using

```
<style>
#msg1 {
  color: red;
}
</style>
```